# Best practice for naming archived objects?

Tags: r, file, parallel-processing

I've got a function that has a *list* output. Every time I run it, I want to export the results with *save*. After a couple of runs I want to read the files in and compare the results. I do this, because I don't know how many tasks there will be, and maybe I'll use different computers to calculate each task. So how should I name the archived objects, so later I can read them all in?

My best guess would be to dynamically name the variables before saving, and keep track of the object names, but I've read everywhere that this is a big no-no.

So how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use the `saveRDS` and `readRDS` functions instead of `save` and `load`.  The RDS version functions will save and read single objects without the attached name.  You would create your object and save it to a file (using `paste0` or `sprintf` to create unique names), then when processing the results you can read in one object at a time, or read several into a list to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope to hide the retrieved name inside a function, so first you might save a list to a file:

```
mybiglist <- list(fred=1, john='dum di dum', mary=3)
save(mybiglist, file='mybiglist1.RData')
```

Then you can load it back in through a function and give it whatever name you like be it inside another list or just a plain object:

```
# Use the fact that load returns the name of the object loaded
# and that scope will hide this object
myspecialload <- function(RD.fnam) {
  return(eval(parse(text=load(RD.fnam))))
}
# now lets reload that file but put it in another object
mynewbiglist <- myspecialload('mybiglist1.RData')

mynewbiglist
$fred
[1] 1

$john
[1] "dum di dum"

$mary
[1] 3
```

Note that this is not really a generic 'use it anywhere' type function, as for an RData file with multiple objects it appears to return the last object saved... so best stick with one list object per file for now!

Answer (score 0):

One time I was given several RData files, and they all had only one variable called x. In order to read all of them in my workspace, I loaded sequentially each the variable to its environment, and I used get() to read its value.

```
tenv <- new.env()
load("file_1.RData", envir = tenv)
ls(tenv) # x
myvar1 <- get(ls(tenv), tenv)
rm(tenv)
....
```

This code can be repeated for each file.